# How to use DictReader in csv package?

Tags: python, csv

I try to import my CA-10-60 file with this code:

```
import csv

with open('CA-10-60.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Contract'], row['Serial'])
```

But I get this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/id984876/PycharmProjects/Search Engine SMC/flask/play.py", line 3, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='')
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictReader'
```

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your code. Please copy and paste it in your question.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of python you are using?

Comment: If you named a file `csv.py`, don't name it that.

Comment: knowa42: I use Python 36

Comment: user2357112: I don't have a file named csv.py mine is called CA-10-60.py

Answer (score 0):

One issue you will definitely have is your delimiter needs to be a one character string as evidenced by what happens when I try and replicate your error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\csv.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

Try fixing that and see if anything changes. As far as I can tell, the csv module is present in both 2.7.14 and 3.6.3 so unless you are running an older version I can't imagine any issues with the import.

Comment: Caleb_McCreary: you mean that I have to called it like this: reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter)

Comment: Caleb_McCreary: I have now idea how to fix this

Comment: @MarcelduCrocq Try calling it like this csv.DictReader(f, delimiter = "  ") - just make sure there is at least one space for the delimiter

Comment: Caleb_McCreary: Error solved next one appears: print(row['Contract'], row['Serial']) KeyError: 'Contract'